# How to attach many jquery events on dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have nav tabs on left side and i am loading content on right side.
I have attched the click event by using live but how can attach these type of functions

```
$('#form').submit(function() { 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
          return false; 
    });
```

---

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                             resizable: true,
                             autoOpen: false,
                             height:427,
                             width:650,
                             modal: true,
                             buttons: { "Ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); },
                                        "Cancel": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
                              });
```

also do i need to attach ajaxoptions as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load new content, you must re-apply things like ".dialog()" from your own code.  Generally, you'd do that in the "success" handler from the ajax mechanism you used to load the content.

What that means is that it's a really good idea to organize your page "widget" setup code so that it can be invoked to operate on an arbitrary portion of the page.  At page initialization time, you'll run it against the `<body>`, but after a dynamic content load you'd run it against the container element that you've updated.

*edit* — more detail:  exactly how you go about doing this is up to you, and it depends on the kinds of things you do in your application. I wrote a [jQuery plugin](http://gutfullofbeer.net/wallflower/doc/) to handle the problem, but that might be overkill for a lot of purposes.

The general idea is that you'd have an initialization function:

```
function initializeFeatures(startingPoint) {
```

Inside the function, you'd do things like initialize dialogs, and you'd base the code that does the work off the "startingPoint" parameter.  In other words, when the code has to "find" page elements to set up, it should always start from there:

```
    $(startingPoint).find('.dialog-container').dialog({
      resizable: true,
      autoOpen: false,
      // ...
    });
```

Then, in your "success" handler after you've loaded content, you can just call your function again:

```
    $('#dynamic').load('/your/url', function() {
      initializeFeatures(this);
    });
```

Again, it completely depends on the exact details of your application.

Comment: You are looking exactly right to me but can you provide some online link so that i can better understand how to achieve , what u r talking about. thanks

Comment: I have put all function in initializefeatures() and then in my ajaxSetup i added this   `complete:function(){      initializeFeatures(this);` and its working fine but i didn't used  $(startingPoint).find . why do i need that

Comment: Well you only need that if you find your page elements with ".foo" or something. For example, if you have some dialog elements on one part of the page, and others that are dynamically loaded, you may not want to initialize some of them twice. But if you always go by "id" anyway, like in your examples, then it does not matter.

Comment: ok ok , now i understand , Everything else is working but `$('#form').submit(function()` is not working even for the first time but if i move it outside function at normal position then it works but not for dynamically loaded elements

Comment: Hmm ... well, I'm not sure why that would be.  One risky thing with dynamic content is that using "id" values can cause problems; if you load some content that uses the same "id" for something as another element on the page, then things may not work. The "id" values must always be unique on a page - in other words, only one element should ever have any particular "id" value. If there are two forms both with the id "form", then that would cause problems. You can use the "class" attribute instead.

Comment: Actually the ids are same but at one point there is only one id on current page as i am overwriting the contents. Also i tried using live on submit and it worked